# DryIoc Registry Class

Tags: dryioc

I Like StructureMap's registry feature for helping me to group IOC Registrations together:

http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/

I'm using DryIOC as my Container - its working great - but I'm in a situation where my registry class needs re-organising.  Is there an equivalent Registry feature in DryIOC?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the Registry feature is similar to Autofac [Module](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html), plus some syntax sugar.

Basically it allows to logically group registrations, simplifying the control.

If I am right,  here is the example of how to group DryIoc registrations in kinda module,  directly comparing with Autofac feature: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/FaqAutofacMigration#markdown-header-modules

The difference from StructureMap is explicit use of injected `IRegistrator`,  instead of hiding it in the base class.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/FaqAutofacMigration.md#modules